# Spring + Hibernate DAO injection fails in Netbeans

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, netbeans

I have controller class LoginData.java

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginData implements Serializable{

@Autowired
private LoginDAO loginDao;

private String username;
private String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void validateUser(){
    try{
        loginDao.login(username, password);
    }catch(BusinessException e){
    }
}

}
```

I am trying to autowire this Dao and its implementation:

LoginDAO

```
public interface LoginDAO {

    public boolean login(String username, String password)throws BusinessException;

    public boolean register(String username, String password, UserType type)throws BusinessException;

}
```

LoginDAOImpl

```
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO{

private String username;
private String password;

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public boolean login(String username, String password) throws BusinessException{
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=:un");
    query.setParameter("un", username);
    if(query.list().size()==0)throw new BusinessException("No user in database!");
    User user = (User)(query.list().get(0));
    return getHashMD5(password).equals(user.getPassword());
}

@Override
public boolean register(String username, String password, UserType type) throws BusinessException{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public static String getHashMD5(String string) throws BusinessException{
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, md.digest(string.getBytes()));
        return bi.toString(16);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

I am also trying to inject sessionFactory in DAO implementation, I don't know if this code will work. My xml for configuration:

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<bean id="loginDAO" class="rs.ac.bg.etf.services.LoginDAOImpl"/>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I get null pointer exception when dao method is called in controller from JSF form. Anyone knows what could be the problem?
PS: xml files are mostly generated by Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Here are duplicate/redundant annotations `@Controller`, `@ManagedBean(name = "login")`, `@SessionScoped`. `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` is needless while using JSF on top of Spring. It is meant for Spring MVC which cannot be used with JSF. `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is also useless and not needed at all in this case (while using JSF on top of Spring - not Spring MVC).

Comment: I need those, my project won't run without any of those.

Comment: Nope. Since beans are managed by Spring, those two annotations `@ManagedBean(name = "login")`, `@SessionScoped` will simply ignored as if they do not exist anymore and the class has only one annotation which is `@Controller` with the default scope `singleton` for Spring beans. It is not a JSF session scoped managed bean but a Spring singleton bean. You need `@Controller` and `@Scope("session")` (from `org.springframework.context.annotation`) instead. `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` are required, when you use Spring MVC which is not the case here

Comment: Do you have sample of xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `@Repository` annotation for the autowiring to work.

Try this:

```
@Repository("LoginDAO")
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO
```

Comment: Nope, I still get NullPointerException.

Comment: Silly me, you need to check your `applicationContext.xml` for `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package"/>` and `<context:annotation-config/>`

Comment: Can you give code example? And this package should point to Dao interface and implementation?

Comment: When I added scan package I had to remove Repository annotation, since it detected dao as double.

Comment: The reason it is repeated is because you have defined loginDAO inside your dispatcher-servlet.xml file. You should remove that.